# spring boot - No auto configuration found in META-INF/spring.factories - gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am creating javafx app with spring boot in background. To do this I used this library: [springboot-javafx-support](https://github.com/roskenet/springboot-javafx-support) Every time when I start it I get exception "No auto configuration found in META-INF/spring.factories". I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I guess it must be something wrong in my gradle build script.

Below you can find gradle.build file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'pl.opfol.subiekt'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.9

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/apt/main'
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar {

    mainClassName = 'pl.opfol.subiekt.util.MainApp'
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://artifact.aspose.com/repo"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/jerady/maven"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging')
    compile('com.h2database:h2:1.4.197')
    compile('javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.1')
    compile('com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.1')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.6')
    compile('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7')
    compile('commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10')
    compile('com.aspose:aspose-words:17.3.0:jdk16')
    compile('com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.4.0.jre9')
    compile('javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2')
    compile('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:9.0.0')
    compile('com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.1')
    compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
    compile('com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.0')
    compile('de.roskenet:springboot-javafx-support:2.1.6')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-controls:9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-weathericons:2.0.10-9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialicons:2.2.0-9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialdesignfont:2.0.26-9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-octicons:4.3.0-9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialstackicons:2.1-5-9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-icons525:4.2.0-9.1.2')
    compile('de.jensd:fontawesomefx-emojione:3.1.1-9.1.2')
    compileOnly ('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.2.16.Final')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Why have you enabled the `jar` task? Depending on the order in which they run one of `bootJar` and `jar` will overwrite the others output.

Comment: Cause I tried everything :) Without jar task the result is the same :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem, make sure you run it on JRE 1.8.